# Multiple main() functions within a Netbeans (C++) project

Tags: c++, netbeans

the problem is the following. We have a (rather large) code base in form of a Netbeans C++ project. On compilation/execution, the program generates/executes a binary which then runs the main program. However, now we need to implement several smaller tools (like compilers, converters, etc.) which use many classes from within that code base.

Is it possible to setup the Netbeans IDE to generate multiple executables from within a single project? Things that would work, but are rather inconvenient cover the following:

- Compile the whole project as both an executable and a library. Use the library to create compilers, converters, etc (we would have to write a lot of extra code...)
- Create different targets, each having an individual macro defined. Use that macro inside the code to exchange the main function (this is just dirty and it doesn't really solve the problem of pushing a single button to compile the main program and all the tools associated with it).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood you project right, but for the task of building several executables I suggest the following: in the build command of your configuration call a script that builds all the executables you need.

Comment: sorry, took me a while to get back to you (^^). Also unsatisfying this really seems to be the only way to go...